# How to make a table column widen when the sidebar ends?

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

Basically I'm working on a table layout for html email and just cannot get the longer of the two columns in my layout to expand when the smaller columns ends. Here's the basic markup:

```
<table>
     <tr>
        <td>
           <table>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                   </td>
               </tr>
        </table>
     </td>
 <td>
    <table>
          <tr>
              <td>
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
              </td>
          </tr>
   </table>
```

So how in the world can I get one of the columns to stretch to 100% width when the smaller columns is no longer in the way? I'm simply trying to avoid having an html email that has a huge long column that only takes up half the width even when there is no other column next to it any more.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first of all you have two tables inside of a table...
This is what a table should look like

```
<table>
<tr> Row 1
<td>
Column 1
</td>
<td>
Column 2
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You shouldn't add tables inside tables, instead just add extra rows or columns as needed.
For a column width to be 100% it doesn't make sense to have two columns.  That said the css would be

```
<td style="width:100%;">Column with width of 100%</td>
```

Hope that helped you out, check out [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/html/) tutorials for more html info!

Answer (score 0):

Consider instead using CSS.. for example this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JDQH8/

```
<p style="border: 1px solid; float:right; width: 50%;">dsfdsfdsfds afasd </p>
<p> dsdsh fhdiuhf afhda fdsi</p>
<p> ashsdhfjoajifjdi a adsf dfdas  </p>
```

I added the border just so you could see the effect

Adam